# Recording multiple USB microphone simulteneously using NAudio library

Tags: usb, microphone, naudio, cross-correlation

I wrote the code to get the mic recording from 3 USB microphones using 3 instances of WaveInEvent.

```
        waveIn.DataAvailable += OnDataAvailable;
        waveIn.RecordingStopped += OnRecordingStopped;
        waveIn.StartRecording();

        waveIn2.DataAvailable += OnDataAvailable2;
        waveIn2.RecordingStopped += OnRecordingStopped;
        waveIn2.StartRecording();
```

In my OnDataAvailable, I do nothing more than writing to a wav file

```
    void waveIn_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
    {
        writer.WriteData(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);

    }
```

I tried manipulating the buffer size but did not really resolve the latency issue. How I am testing this is I place microphone right next to each other and record, if I run cross-correlation from these data, I should ideally be getting ~0 sample lag.

It would be ideal if I can get all signals from multiple microphones "at the same time" with no latency between different microphones. However, I noticed few sample delays between different microphones.

I know that for this sort of application that require no/low latency, NAudio is not preferable. I was wondering if I can reduce the latency between different USB mic further by using WASAPI or if you would suggest using other libraries...

Answer (score 0):

In my experience latency of usb audio devices vary with the device type, driver and even the usb port. So you probably need to tune the latencies for perfect fit.

This could be possible with the BufferedWaveProvider. 
Write data to it in your waveIn_DataAvailable. You can adjust the buffer size of each of the buffered wave providers which in turn adjusts their delay. Maybe you can tune the different delays to sync up your mics.

Of course you could run into the same problem as with adjusting the waveIn buffers. LAnguages running in the CLR (like C#) are non-deterministic with a time uncertainty of 10-20ms, which could make your task impossible.